# Is it possible to record clips less than a minute in length?

Tags: recording, shadowplay

Is there any way to get Nvidia ShadowPlay to record clips less than a minute in length?

Answer (score 3):

If you manually record your gameplay, you may record as much or as little as you wish. To do that, you need to first set the recording mode to `Manual` or `Shadow & Manual`. After that, just start recording by using the hotkey you set under `Toggle manual recording on/off and save`, then stop it by using the same hotkey.

If you're talking about Shadow recording, there is no way to set it to record less than 1 minute. The point of Shadow recording, is that it records for as long as possible, so that you can save a record in hindsight. It allows you to catch those special moments you least expected, or the ones you forgot to start recording. Setting it to less than 1 minute would pretty much defeat the whole point of Shadow recording.

If you're worried about the space a 1 minute Shadow recording takes, you may always reduce the video quality and/or its resolution. If you don't want to, you'll have to invest in a larger storage device.

Comment: The reason i want this is that i have found the moments i wanted to record typically last between 30 and 10 seconds. I could look into batch clip processing, but finding a shadowplay workaround seemed easier.